# Listening to a multicast UDP address

Tags: java, matlab, udp, multicast

I wrote an application in MATLAB to open a UDP socket and listen for incoming datagrams. Basically, something like this:

```
u = udp(rHost, rPort, 'LocalHost', lHost, 'LocalPort', lPort);
u.DatagramAvailableFcn = @(o,e) operateOnData(o,e);
fopen(u);
```

This works wonderfully when I'm listening to something in a unicast fashion. But I would now like to be able to listen to multicast traffic. Apparently, [this isn't possible in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91896-is-it-possible-to-connect-to-a-udp-multicast-using-the-instrument-control-toolbox-2-2-r14sp2).

The workaround is, per above link,

> > As a workaround to connect to a UDP multicast, you can do the following:
> >
> > 1. Use a Java multicast socket to access it directly from MATLAB. For more information, see javadoc or tutorials for the "core java.net" classes from Sun, specifically "java.net.MulticastSocket". This could be found at:
> >
> > http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html

I have no background in Java so this is a struggle for me. I've only been able to run the following to instantiate a `MulticastSocket` object:

```
>> ms = javaObject('java.net.MulticastSocket');
```

I looked around and found that I also need a `java.net.Datagram` object to actually contain the incoming stream.

How do I use the `MulticastSocket` and `Datagram` objects within the context of MATLAB? I'm trying to replicate the functionality of `u.DatagramAvailableFcn`, i.e., fire a callback to operate on the contents of the datagram once I receive one.

**EDIT**: Looks like [this is how I want to go about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4405143/238644) in terms of the Java, but now it's getting this back into MATLAB-land...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully subscribed and received a packet from a multicast stream, by the following:

```
socket = java.net.MultiSocket(streamPort);
socket.joinGroup(java.net.InetAddress.getByName(streamIP));
socket.setReuseAddress(1);

packet = java.net.DatagramPacket(zeros(1, intmax('uint16'), 'int8'), intmax('uint16'));

socket.receive(packet);

socket.leaveGroup(InetAddress.getByName(streamIP));
socket.close;

msg = packet.getData;
msg = msg(1:packet.getLength);
```

This was essentially lifted from [`judp`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24525-a-simple-udp-communications-application) availble on the MathWorks File Exchange.

I am still looking for a way to get some equivalent of a `DatagramReceivedFcn` - right now it looks like the `socket.receive` call is blocking until it times out. I can use `timer` objects to fire the "callback" on a regular basis but that's of course not the same as having a `DatagramReceivedFcn`.